# how to use std::allocator in a delete/new operator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have made a template which is suposed to take custom allocator, like this:

```
template<typename Key,typename Alloc=std::allocator<Key>>
struct node {
   typedef typename Alloc::template rebind<node>::other allocator_type;
   void* operator new(size_t size)  {
      node* n = _node_allocator.allocate(1);
      _node_allocator.construct(n, _node_init_val);
      return n;
   }
   void operator delete(void * n)
   {
      _node_allocator.destroy(static_cast<node*>(n));
      _node_allocator.deallocate(static_cast<node*>(n), 1);
   }
   node() {std::cout<<"Constr init"<<std::endl;}
   node(Key x):_k(x) {std::cout<<"Constructor"<<std::endl;}
   ~node() { std::cout<<"Destructor"<<std::endl;}
protected:
   Key _k;
   static allocator_type _node_allocator;
   static const node _node_init_val;
};

template<typename Key,typename Alloc> 
const node<Key,Alloc> node<Key,Alloc>::_node_init_val;

template<typename Key,typename Alloc>
typename node<Key,Alloc>::allocator_type node<Key,Alloc>::_node_allocator;

int main() {
    node<int>* p=new node<int>(5);
    delete p;
    std::cout<<"END"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately the destructor is called twice because delete always implicit calls the destructor, but I think that this will not do since the allacation is made by
_node_allocator and therefor the destruction should also be made by using _node_allocator. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Don't call destroy from operator delete, also don't call construct from operator new. These functions should allocate and deallocate memory, nothing else.

Comment: Maybe but then I will have a problem by specifying alternative initializations for the struct without making a specialization for the whole struct. Right now I suppose I can make many spezialised _node_init_val

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: @ralismark I want to use my _node_init_val to initialize my object when it is created. The _node_init_val can be specialized for Key=string like this:
    template<typename Alloc>
    const node<std::string,Alloc> _node_init_val("cat");
So when Key is different from string it is the default template is used, seen in my question above otherwise the specialized template is used. However it seems I cannot use _node_init_val in my new operator.